# Excel formula using countif

Tags: excel-formula

There are 11 numbers in a column.

```
5 
5
5
5
12
13
5
9
2
5
10
```

I need to build a formula that tells me how many times occurs the following situation: Number is bigger than each of previous four numbers.

In this case the situation occurs 3 times. By:

```
12 bigger than 5;5;5;5
13 bigger than 12;5;5;5
10 bigger than  5;2;9;5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data starts in `A1` you can use `if()` and `max()` to do this. Add this to `B5` (next to the 12 in your example):

```
=IF(MAX(A1:A4)<A5, 1, "")
```

This will put a `1` next to `12`. You can copy this formula down to find the other values where this is true.

This works by looking at the `MAX()` value of the previous 4 values. `IF()` they are higher than the current value, then it prints a 1.

Comment: and then you need to take the sum of colum B to get your count of how many times it has happened